# Jackson : Partially update bean with json String

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am writing a test suite which includes pinging an API with different payload. Below is the sample payload (example):

```
{
   "param_1" : "value_1",
   "param_2" : "value_2",
   "param_3" : "value_3",
   "param_4" : "value_4",
   "param_5" : "value_5",
   "location" : {
        "region" : "EU"
   },
   "additional_params" : {
        "availability" : "high",
        "volume" : "low"
   }
}
```

I have the above payload written in `json` file and the test suite performs the following:

- Read the `json` file and create a bean for payload
- Send the `POST` request
- Assert the response

Now, I need to test the same API with different combinations of values, e.g. US region, low availability, low volume etc. The request has lots of other parameters but only the above ones change. To test this, I can do the following:

- Create a `json` file with each scenario
- Create just one `json` file, deserialize it and store the combinations into another file like this:

```
[
  {
    "location": {
        "region": "US"
    },
    "additional_params" : {
        "availability" : "high",
        "volume" : "high"
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
        "region": "EU"
    },
    "additional_params" : {
        "availability" : "low",
        "volume" : "low"
    }
  }
]
```

I can then read this file, update the base object every time before sending the request.

The problem with the first approach is, I will end up with lots of files with 90% duplicate content. For the second approach, does the jackson provide the APIs to deserialise base object and apply the changes like I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

> For the second approach, does Jackson provide the APIs to deserialise base object and apply the changes like I mentioned above?

Well, Jackson provides something that might be useful for you. I don't know exactly how you are structuring your tests, but one possible approach could be using [`@JacksonInject`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonInject.html), as it allows a value to be injected in your bean.

You could define model classes as following:

```java
@Data
public class Payload {

    private Location location;

    @JsonProperty("additional_params")
    private AdditionalParameters additionalParameters;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Location {

    @JacksonInject("region")
    private String region;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class AdditionalParameters {

    @JacksonInject("availability")
    private String availability;

    @JacksonInject("volume")
    private String volume;
}
```

Then you could use:

```java
String json = "{\n"
        + "    \"location\": {},\n"
        + "    \"additional_params\": {}\n"
        + "  }";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setInjectableValues(new InjectableValues.Std()
        .addValue("region", "EU")
        .addValue("availability", "high")
        .addValue("volume", "low")
);

Payload payload = mapper.readValue(json, Payload.class);
```